# Extjs 4.2 Grid Design With Fixed/Constant Values

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4.2, gridpanel

I want to create a table like below.
[image: ![![enter image description here]

On the left side there are fixed values, the row belonging to the checked ones will be filled.
Even if the rows are empty, the values on the left should be display.
How can I design this in ExtJS 4.2?